# Why does JSLint give strict violation error on this function?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, jslint, webstorm, use-strict

JSLint gives me the "strict violation" error, although I use the "this" context inside a function which hides it from the global scope.

```
function test() {
    "use strict";
    this.a = "b";
}
```

For the record, I use the built-in JSLint parser in Webstorm.

Comment: When I paste this code into JSLint.com, all default options, I do not receive an error.  What was the context of the error where changing the function name removed it?

Comment: I'm using Webstorm which maybe has an outdated version of JSLint

Comment: Any chance you have two functions named (the equivalent of) `test` (in your live code)?  Then changing case would make them different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because JSLint doesn't recognize your function as a constructor. By convention, you must use uppercase letters.

```
function Test() {
    "use strict";
    this.a = "b";
}
```

Comment: You might look at http://jshint.com. It offers more control, rather than locking you into options controlled by Crockford's opinion rather than the specification. The problem you've run into also happens with non-constructors, if you are declaring functions you're going to put on an object as methods. (For instance, if after your `function test(){...}` you had `obj.test = test;` so you ended up with a function with a proper name on the `test` property, but without using a named function expression because of the problems IE has with them.)