# Getting warning don't make functions within a loop jslint

Tags: javascript, dom, jslint

I'm Getting warning don't make functions within a loop on my code i'm using jslint my questions are

1. is it ok to ignore this warning.
2. how can i rectify this any alternative.

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/cannelflow/9sw0nzcv/)

```js
/*global prompt,alert,console,rgb*/
/*jslint plusplus: true */
/*jshint loopfunc: true */
var colors = [
    'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
    'rgb(255, 255, 0)',
    'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
    'rgb(0, 255, 255)',
    'rgb(0, 255, 0)',
    'rgb(0, 0, 255)'
];

var pickedColor = colors[2];
var square = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
var i;
var colorMatch = document.querySelector(".pickedColor");
for (i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
    //add different color to square
    square[i].style.background = colors[i];
    //add eventlistner to square
    square[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        'use strict';
        var selectedColor = (this.style.background);
        if (selectedColor === pickedColor) {
            console.log("True");
        } else {
            console.log('False');
        }
    });
}
colorMatch.textContent = pickedColor;
```

```css
body{
    background: rgb(52, 73, 94);
}
h1{
    color: white;
}
.container{
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
}
.square{
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1.66%;
    background-color: purple;
    padding-bottom: 30%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Color Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <h1>The Great <spam class="pickedColor"
   >RGB</spam> Color Game</h1>
   <div class="container">
       <div class="square"></div>
       <div class="square"></div>
       <div class="square"></div>
       <div class="square"></div>
       <div class="square"></div>
       <div class="square"></div>
   </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

In the meantime, thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that **specific** case, you could ignore the warning, because your functions don't use any variables they close over (like `i`) that change in the course of the loop.

But since they don't, there's no reason to create several copies of the function when just one will do:

```
function squareClick() {
    'use strict';
    var selectedColor = (this.style.background);
    if (selectedColor === pickedColor) {
        console.log("True");
    } else {
        console.log('False');
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
    //add different color to square
    square[i].style.background = colors[i];
    //add eventlistner to square
    square[i].addEventListener('click', squareClick);
}
```

---

Where it would be a problem:

Suppose you did this and there were 8 squares:

```
for (i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
    square[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(i); // <=== Using i
    });
}
```

When you clicked those squares, you'd see the value 8, no matter which square you clicked, because those functions have a *live reference* to the `i` variable, not a copy of the variable as of when they were created.

That's part of why jsLint warns you about this: Either you need to be careful (because you're using `i`), or it's pointless to create functions in the loop (because you aren't using anything that varies).

Final note: In ES2015, you could safely do this:

```
for (let n = 0; n < square.length; n++) {
    square[n].addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert(n); // <=== Using n
    });
}
```

...and you'd see 0, 1, 2, ... 7 depending on what square you clicked. This is because the ES2015+ semantics of the `let` declarations *within* `for` loops is specifically designed to ensure that each loop iteration gets its own copy of `n`. This is **very different** from the seemingly-near-identical version using `var`.

Example with `var`; they all show 8:

```js
var square = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
for (var i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
  square[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(i); // <=== Using i
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="square">zero</div>
<div class="square">one</div>
<div class="square">two</div>
<div class="square">three</div>
<div class="square">four</div>
<div class="square">five</div>
<div class="square">six</div>
<div class="square">seven</div>
```

Example with `let` (on ES2015+ compliant browsers); they show 0...7:

```js
var square = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
for (let n = 0; n < square.length; n++) {
  square[n].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(n); // <=== Using n
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="square">zero</div>
<div class="square">one</div>
<div class="square">two</div>
<div class="square">three</div>
<div class="square">four</div>
<div class="square">five</div>
<div class="square">six</div>
<div class="square">seven</div>
```

Note that the `let` has to be *within* the `for` for this treatment to kick in. That is,

```
let n;
for (n = 0; n < square.length; ++n)
```

is **very different** from

```
for (let n = 0; n < square.length; ++n)
```

The former would act like `var` in terms of functions created within the loop. The latter does not.

Comment: worked f9 now i got 'Strict violation' var selectedColor = (this.style.background); so edited as said in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770048/why-does-jslint-give-strict-violation-error-on-this-function

Comment: @user5323957: If you mean you capitalized it, you don't want to do that, it gives the impression that `squareClick` is a constructor, when it isn't. jslint's "strict violation" on that line is just nonsense, because Crockford doesn't like normal use of JavaScript. I'd strongly recommend you use a tool like [jshint](http://jshint.com/) or [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) instead, which is less biased toward non-standard use of the language.

Comment: @user5323957: Side note: There's no point to the `()` in `var selectedColor = (this.style.background);` at all, they don't do anything.

Answer (score 4):

For performance reasons, creating functions takes some time, so if it doesn't have to be done multiple times (in a loop), that's better. You can just define your function before the loop in reference it inside:

```
function handler() {
        'use strict';
        var selectedColor = (this.style.background);
        if (selectedColor === pickedColor) {
            console.log("True");
        } else {
            console.log('False');
        }
    }

for (i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
    //add different color to square
    square[i].style.background = colors[i];
    //add eventlistner to square
    square[i].addEventListener('click', handler);
}
```

Comment: *"...creating functions takes some time"* "takes some time" suggests that it's slow. It isn't, remotely, slow. It *does* take non-zero time, but unless `square.length` is in the hundreds of thousands (if not more, perhaps), nothing perceptible.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating potentially dozens of copies of a function, make one and use a reference.

```
var square_listener = function() {
    var selectedColor = (this.style.background);
    if (selectedColor === pickedColor) {
        console.log("True");
    } else {
        console.log('False');
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < square.length; i++) {
    square[i].style.background = colors[i];
    square[i].addEventListener('click', square_listener);
}
```